# What is the abstract definition of a Mathematical transform?

Tags: definition, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, transformation

The question is What is the abstract definition of a Mathematical transform? Is there any book talking specifically about what makes a Mathematical transform a Mathematical transform?

I am particularly talking about Fourier, Laplace, Wavelet and other transforms of the same kind. For instance, how can I know the map I have devised is a transform or not?

Furthermore, any books and references regarding the question would be much appreciated.

Comment: See this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform).

Comment: @William The problem is most books on integral equation do not address my question regarding transforms. My question is specific but integral equations field is a broad answer to this specific question.

Comment: What does what "of the same kind" means here?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact definition but I've noticed mathematical transforms typically   transform a function in one variable to a function in another variable using a definite integral over an infinite integration range (e.g. $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,g(x\,y)\,dx$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,g(x\,y)\,dx$, or $\int_{-i\,\infty}^{i\,\infty} f(x)\,g(x\,y)\,dx$). Note this is different than a definite integral such as $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ or indefinite integral $\int_0^y f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @FreeMind I do not understand your response. You asked for the definition of a transform, which is a broad question.

Comment: @William It is indeed a broad question. But I am asking for abstract definition of the transform which covers all forms of transform. A book on this topic which also gives examples related to Fourier and other transforms would be good.

Comment: @ArcticChar In the same area.

Comment: See Distribution Theory and Transform Analysis, A. H. Zemanian.  Dover Press.  1987.  But personally, I think Chapter 2 of Green's Functions and Boundary Value Problems, Stackgold, Wiley (2011) is much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the abstract definition of a Mathematical transform?
> ... I am particularly talking about Fourier, Laplace, Wavelet and other transforms of the same kind.

All three of those are "integral transforms", defined in places like [the English Wikipedia page for "integral transform"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) as:

> any transform $T$ of the ... form: $(Tf)(u)={\displaystyle \int_{t_1}^{t_2}}f(t)K(t,u)\,\mathrm dt$

---

> For instance, how can I know the map I have devised is a transform or not?

If you defined it via an integral like the above, it's an integral transform. If you didn't, then it isn't an integral transform, but there's a very tiny chance it coincidentally equals an integral transform.

---

> Furthermore, any books and references regarding the question would be much appreciated.

This is not my field of study, but I imagine books with "integral transforms" in their title might be appropriate or help you find other sources, depending on your interests/goals. For example, "Integral Transforms and their Applications", "Introduction to Integral Transforms", "Integral Transforms and Operational Calculus", "Integral Transforms in Applied Mathematics", etc.

If you have a more specific question about the best book for a certain goal, that might be worth making a separate question on Math StackExchange with the full context.